# use function and label in tk inter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a "ROCK-PAPER-SICCORS" program and I use Tkinter.
but there is a problem when I want to change the "user_choise" in the "user" function.
when the program starts 3 buttons are visible in the screen and user should select one of them and the "user_choice" variable changes based user's selection.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

#global variebels
pc_point=0
user_point=0


window=Tk()
window.title("ROCK - PAPER - SICCOR")
window.minsize(250,250)


#functions
def greeting():
    #print("welcome",user_name.get())
    greeting_label.config(text="welcome {}".format(user_name.get()))


def user():
    pass



user_choice=Label(window,text="")
user_choice.pack()
#name box
name=Label(window,text="Enter your name")
name.pack()

user_name=Entry(window)
user_name.pack()

#submit users name
Button(window,text="submit",command=greeting).pack()
greeting_label=Label(window,text="")
greeting_label.pack()

#points
point_user=Label(window,text="You: ")
point_user.pack()

point_pc=Label(window,text="PC: ")
point_pc.pack()

#Buttons
rock_btn=Button(window,text="ROCK",activebackground="blue",width=10,anchor=CENTER,command=user)
rock_btn.pack()

paper_btn=Button(window,text="PAPER",activebackground="blue",width=10,anchor=CENTER)
paper_btn.pack()

siccors_btn=Button(window,text="SICCORS",activebackground="blue",width=10,anchor=CENTER)
siccors_btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"but there is a problem"_ - what is the problem? Is the program crashing? Are you getting an error (and if so, what is the error?). Is it updating the wrong thing? Is it updating the right thing with the wrong information? ...

Comment: I don't know what I should write in the "user" function

Comment: That would be determined based on how you expect this to work. It would appear you plan on using the `user` function with your buttons (since you already have the `ROCK` button command set).  You should probably come up with conditions that allow the buttons to all use the function `user` and subsequently determine the correct selection based on some `if` `elif` `else` statements.